# Semantic-UI Modal blows my Pushable Sidebar

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, semantic-ui, sidebar, semantic-ui-react

I'm using Semantic-UI-React in a very simple front end. The main page is using a `Sidebar.Pushable` to show a menu and the main content. If any of the sub-components opens a `Modal`, the `Sidebar` stops reacting. No error - I assume it's something to do with some CSS irrevocably changed at some level. Once a `Modal` is opened anywhere in the app, the only way to get the `Sidebar` to be pushable again is to reload the page.

I did my best to drill into the CSS, but I'm still missing it. There's [an ancient issue on Github](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/2964), dealing with similar behavior in semantic-ui itself (i.e. no React involved), but no conclusive solution.

To recreate, just [use the code from the Sidebar example](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar/#types-sidebar), and add a button that opens a Modal in the `Pusher`. Once the `Modal` is open, the `Sidebar` is dead.

I've created a [Sandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-tree-r5m0o).

Update: opened a Github issue: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/4110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this has been fixed in semantic-ui-react@2.0.3 . See [this issue](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/4110) for details.

Comment: Iknow - I opened the issue. Also uploaded same code with working sample :)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue and found a workaround.

First I add a dummy className to the trigger of the Sidebar.
Then in the onHide handle I check the target and if it is the class I don't set the state.

```
<Button size='huge' className="NoClose" icon style={{marginTop: '1em'}}
    onClick={this.setVisible}><Icon className="NoClose" name='list' /> Menu</Button>

handleOnHide = (e, data) => {
    if(!e.target.classList.contains('NoClose')){
        this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible });
    }
}
```

Hope it can help until a real fix is found

Comment: i'm not sure I understand your solution. Tried replicating it unsuccessfully. Can you try creating a sandbox based on mine to demonstrate?

Comment: I'm not sure how to make it with function components but with class it looks like this :
https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-elbakyan-88r5f?file=/src/App.js
https://88r5f.csb.app/

Comment: Your sample doesn't work: I can't collapse the sidebar once opened, and the sidebar doesn't work once the modal is used. Am I missing anything?

Comment: It does not work in the sandbox but use this link (it works for me) https://88r5f.csb.app/

Comment: Gotcha. Really appreciate the hack and the effort :). I'll see if it can work in my project.

Comment: Had the same issue. This worked for me. Since my button also has an icon, the only check I need from `onHide` is whether `e.target.classList.contains('icon')` is false.